# Modelview programming in PyQt4

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyqt

In my first attempt, I have tried to load images from disk and load it to a `QTableView` using `QAbstractTableModel`.  I'd like a general code review of this code.

```
import sys
import os

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyListModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel): 
    def __init__(self, datain, col, thumbRes, parent=None): 
        """ datain: a list where each item is a row
        """
        self._thumbRes = thumbRes
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent) 
        self._listdata = datain
        self._col = col
        self.pixmap_cache = {}

    def colData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation in [QtCore.Qt.Vertical, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal]:
                return None

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        return len(self._listdata) 

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return self._col

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole:
            return  QtCore.QSize(*self._thumbRes)

        if role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter

        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            try:
                fileName = os.path.split(self._listdata[row][column])[-1]
            except IndexError:
                return
            return fileName

        if role == QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            try:
                self.selectonChanged(row,column)
                fileName = os.path.split(self._listdata[row][column])[-1]
            except IndexError:
                return
            return QtCore.QString(fileName)

        if index.isValid() and role == QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            try:
                value = self._listdata[row][column]
            except IndexError:
                return

            pixmap = None
            # value is image path as key
            if self.pixmap_cache.has_key(value) == False:
                pixmap=self.generatePixmap(value)
                self.pixmap_cache[value] =  pixmap
            else:
                pixmap = self.pixmap_cache[value]
            return QtGui.QImage(pixmap).scaled(self._thumbRes[0],self._thumbRes[1], 
                QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

        if index.isValid() and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            try:
                value = self._listdata[row][column]
                fileName = os.path.split(value)[-1]
            except IndexError:
                return
            return os.path.splitext(fileName)[0]

    def generatePixmap(self, value):
        pixmap=QtGui.QPixmap()
        pixmap.load(value)
        return pixmap

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            try:
                newName = os.path.join(str(os.path.split(self._listdata[row][column])[0]), str(value.toString()))
            except IndexError:
                return
            self.__renameFile(self._listdata[row][column], newName)
            self._listdata[row][column] = newName
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        return False

    def selectonChanged(self, row, column):
        # TODO Image scale
        pass


    def __renameFile(self, fileToRename, newName):
        try:
            os.rename(str(fileToRename), newName)
        except Exception, err:
            print err


class MyTableView(QtGui.QTableView):
    """docstring for MyTableView"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyTableView, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Widget | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint)
        sw = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(self).width()
        sh = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(self).height()
        self.setGeometry(0,0,sw,sh)
        self.showFullScreen()

        thumbWidth = 300
        thumbheight = 420
        col = sw/thumbWidth 
        self.setColumnWidth(thumbWidth, thumbheight)
        crntDir = "/Users/UserName/Pictures/"
        # create table
        list_data = []
        philes = os.listdir(crntDir)
        for phile in philes:
            if phile.endswith(".png") or phile.endswith("jpg"):
                list_data.append(os.path.join(crntDir, phile))
        _twoDLst = convertToTwoDList(list_data, col)

        lm = MyListModel(_twoDLst, col, (thumbWidth, thumbheight), self)
        self.setShowGrid(False)

        self.setWordWrap(True)
        self.setModel(lm)
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()

    def keyPressEvent(self, keyevent):
        """ Capture key to exit, next image, previous image,
            on Escape , Key Right and key left respectively.
        """
        event = keyevent.key()
        if event == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()

def convertToTwoDList(l, n): 
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window =  MyTableView()
    window.show()
    window.raise_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

### Abstract Model

There are a few improvements I could see in your table model class:

1. In `data()` you could use `elif` for all of the if-statements past the first. This will save the need to evaluate each if-condition after the first condition that was found to be `True`
2. Use `key in dict` notation. You have this line in your `data()` method:

   ```
   if self.pixmap_cache.has_key(value) == False:
   ```

   This can be written simpler and more Pythonic-ly as:

   ```
   if not value in self.pixmap_cache:
   ```
3. In `setData()` you caste the result from `os.path.split()` to a `str`. This is not necessary as `os.path.split()` returns a tuple containing strings.
4. Finally, in your `selectionChanged()` function, raise a `NotImplementedError` instead of `pass`ing. Just in case.

### Table

1. In your `__init__()` function, you set the current directory. You have hard-coded some basic user information. Instead, use the function `os.path.expanduser`. This will expand `~` into the current user's information.

   ```
   crntDir = os.path.expanduser('~/Pictures/')
   ```
2. In your for-loop checking for file extensions, you simply check for `phile.endswith('jpg')`. This will match **anything** that ends with `jpg`, including directories. Add the period and it will be fixed.
3. There is no need to store `MyListModel` in a variable. Just go ahead and declare it in `self.setModel()`.

### General Comments

1. In your `convertToTwoDList` function, make your variable names more descriptive. They are very ambiguous at the moment.
2. Look over the PEP8 style guide. It will help your code look more Pythonic. A few examples:
   `use_underscores` in variable names instead of `camelCase`. Keep consistent spacing throughout your code. Overall it looks very good, however there are times where you have double-blank lines in-between methods.